# connecting to cB-OLP425 in background iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background-process, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to connect to a cB-OLP425 ble device while the app is in the background.  I have done everything I can find to do on the web.  I have set the advertising interval to 20ms like this in connect blue's cb.demo.c using IAR embededWorkbench.

```
void gapSetAlwaysAdvertising(void)
{
uint8 advertising_enable = TRUE;
uint16 desired_min_advertising_interval = 20; **//I'M ASSUMING THIS IS 20ms changed it from 1600**
int16 desired_max_advertising_interval = 2500;

uint8 advertData[] = 0x02,  //length of first data structure (2 bytes excluding length byte)
**//I'm thinking I need to change this to 0x05 which is 30 sec. am I correct**

GAP_ADTYPE_FLAGS,  //AD Type = Flags
GAP_ADTYPE_FLAGS_GENERAL | GAP_ADTYPE_FLAGS_BREDR_NOT_SUPPORTED
};
```

I have made the so that it connects only to one particular module by renaming it's local name and then only allowing to connect to that name.

Somewhere I read that this may be a problem in that in background this may be left off?

I use this code for finding module

```
- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        self.characteristicsCBUUID = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        self.myPeripherals = [NSMutableArray new];

        manager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
    }

    return self;
}


- (void)startScan
{
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE], CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey, nil];

    [manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:self.myPeripherals options:options];



}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSLog(@"Did discover peripheral. peripheral: %@ rssi: %@, UUID: %@ advertisementData: %@ ", peripheral, RSSI, peripheral.UUID, advertisementData);
    NSDictionary *dataDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Specialname" forKey:@"kCBAdvDataLocalName" ];

    if(![self.myPeripherals containsObject:peripheral])
        [self.myPeripherals addObject:peripheral];
   if ([advertisementData isEqualToDictionary:dataDict]) {



    [manager retrievePeripherals:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(id) peripheral.UUID]];

        }
}
```

I have added the correct information into the apps Plist for functionality in background mode.
not however audio since I heard Apple won't approve this if it is just added to keep app from going to sleep.

Does anyone have any suggestions or see where I need to change/add anything.  I'm starting to get frustrated.

Thanks for any and all help

Answer (score 0):

For background mode central, use plist key "bluetooth-central" like this:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
<string>bluetooth-central</string>
</array>
```

Note that in background mode, you can only scan for devices with pre-defined UUID services.
Also, when getting peripheral advertisements in background mode, you do not always have the "local-name" part of the advertisement data.

Actually, in my peripheral BTLE app, when in background mode, the advertising does not include the "local-name".

What I did to ensure that I connect my central with the proper peripheral is I generated a UUID from my central, stored it in my peripheral, with some sort of custom pairing procedure. 
This way, my peripheral app in background mode advertises the service UUID previously generated by my central, and the central can recognize it even without its local-name.

Comment: sorry it took me so long to respond but I was in the middle of another project.  Can you show me where and how I would do this custom pairing without the local name